# Spring Boot working only in the IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm developing a Spring Boot application using IntelliJ and I'm trying to create an executable JAR.

In the IDE it's all working fine but when I create an executable JAR and run it via the CMD, I get all kinds of errors.

My Main lookes like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

And then I get this:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
    at my.app.Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:204)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

I can't find why is it like that and how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated.

My Gradle build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'my.app'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.graphql-java:graphql-java:9.0'
    compile 'com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:5.1.0'
    compile 'com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:4.2.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-couchbase:3.0.8.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.2.Final'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.2'
    compile 'com.beust:klaxon:3.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

The lib dir includes these files:

```
classmate-1.3.4.jar
hibernate-validator-6.0.9.Final.jar
jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
jackson-core-2.9.5.jar
jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar
jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.5.jar
jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.5.jar
jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.5.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar
logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
logback-core-1.2.3.jar
reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
snakeyaml-1.19.jar
spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-indexer-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-jcl-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-jcl-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-webflux-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-websocket-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.jar
Hibernate.jar
tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar
tomcat-embed-el-8.5.31.jar
tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar
validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
```

Comment: The fact that you needed to add the `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` is already an indication that something is wrong. Post your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` and show the dependencies and also post the full stacktrace not only the message.

Comment: The most important information is the reason for the exception which will be way down the stacktrace. Please post it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I edited the question according to your comment

Comment: There is nothing boot related in your build file... So how should spring boot know how to build an executable jar and include the proper dependencies? They aren't in your list of dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have the Spring Boot JAR files in my lib folder. The IntelliJ artifact settings are that to extract all the JARs in the lib folder into the final executable JAR.

Comment: Don't do that. Don't invent your own mechanism. You need the spring boot plugin to create a valid executable jar. Don't try to outsmart the framework work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one in your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or/and also this one :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and try to remove :

```
 @Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
}
```

from the main

Comment: I have both these as jar files

Comment: strange.. however generally I don' t insert this code in the main when i generate a jar file:           
    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    }